# Add new tag and value to existing SWIFT Iso Complaint message

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to add a tag to existing SWIFT message , without rebuilding the whole SWIFT message.

I tried using prowidesoftware , but the tags added in block 4 is not in same sequence as ISO prescribed standard

Tags got added at last in block 4

Is there any other library which can help this case

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that Stack Overflow is not made to ask for tutorial nor video, book, technologie or library recommendation. Please use Stack Overflow to get help with code and see [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)